# Replacing code with link to a file in ghost blog hbs

Tags: handlebars.js, bokeh, ghost-blog

I am using the file_html function in bokeh to produce html that I want to embed into a ghost blog website.

If I load the id in a html card on the site, and then paste the head and body of the file into a code injection/header window, the output is fine.

But the html files can be long. So, rather than pasting the code, I want to save the file in my theme, and then include a link to that file. I've tried different ways, but can't get the chart to show.

This is what pasting the head/body into the code injection header looks like:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
    </script>

<script type="application/json" id="1653">
      {"1f335636-847c-44ca-ac3d-a39e52279a15":{"defs":[],"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.2,"line_color":"blue","x":{"field":"Date"},"y":{"field":"A"}},"id":"1474","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"coordinates":null,"formatter":{"id":"1483"},"group":null,"major_label_policy":{"id":"1484"},"ticker":{"id":"1449"}},"id":"1448","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1483","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"coordinates":null,"formatter":{"id":"1480"},"group":null,"major_label_policy":{"id":"1481"},"ticker":{"id":"1453"}},"id":"1452","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"data":{"A":{"__ndarray__":"q2jSD7sDvr+pDX3hPMntvxSFJEWY1eg/MVje9zOj8L+47dbtoFzTPw4XszUKu+0/","dtype":"float64","order":"little","shape":[6]},"B":{"__ndarray__":"1i8GC4Oi8D+uLg3FLEbsvwTnKftsKAPArl2CHJBq5L9l8duvR2/hPzi+J1DhqPA/","dtype":"float64","order":"little","shape":[6]},"C":{"__ndarray__":"hrXr9J6Xdr+t0s/xTnjKvxrjdAWjo/k/9U9XIzQq5D9rBurlogrxP0qoktgjAPg/","dtype":"float64","order":"little","shape":[6]},"D":{"__ndarray__":"s0qFVyjEtL+e/bFQtfTdv46B45hT4Mq/ftVSa9MK7b+DcTodgFj5P8Bs4A3NS/e/","dtype":"float64","order":"little","shape":[6]},"Date":{"__ndarray__":"AAAA57Nrd0IAAMBMBmx3QgAAgLJYbHdCAABAGKtsd0IAAAB+/Wx3QgAAwONPbXdC","dtype":"float64","order":"little","shape":[6]}},"selected":{"id":"1486"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1485"}},"id":"1437","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1440","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"blue","x":{"field":"Date"},"y":{"field":"A"}},"id":"1473","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1484","type":"AllLabels"},{"attributes":{"coordinates":null,"data_source":{"id":"1437"},"glyph":{"id":"1491"},"group":null,"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":{"id":"1493"},"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1492"},"view":{"id":"1495"}},"id":"1494","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1459","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1442","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"line_color":"blue","x":{"field":"Date"},"y":{"field":"A"}},"id":"1472","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1453","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1457","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"1448"}],"center":[{"id":"1451"},{"id":"1455"},{"id":"1488"}],"left":[{"id":"1452"}],"renderers":[{"id":"1475"},{"id":"1494"}],"title":{"id":"1470"},"toolbar":{"id":"1463"},"x_range":{"id":"1440"},"x_scale":{"id":"1444"},"y_range":{"id":"1442"},"y_scale":{"id":"1446"}},"id":"1439","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"axis":{"id":"1452"},"coordinates":null,"dimension":1,"group":null,"ticker":null},"id":"1455","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"1462"}},"id":"1458","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"tools":[{"id":"1456"},{"id":"1457"},{"id":"1458"},{"id":"1459"},{"id":"1460"},{"id":"1461"},{"id":"1508"}]},"id":"1463","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1485","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1437"}},"id":"1476","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"label":{"value":"A"},"renderers":[{"id":"1475"}]},"id":"1489","type":"LegendItem"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1486","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","coordinates":null,"fill_alpha":0.5,"fill_color":"lightgrey","group":null,"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":1.0,"line_color":"black","line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":2,"right_units":"screen","syncable":false,"top_units":"screen"},"id":"1462","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1456","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1446","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"coordinates":null,"group":null,"text":"Trial"},"id":"1470","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1480","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"coordinates":null,"group":null,"items":[{"id":"1489"},{"id":"1507"}]},"id":"1488","type":"Legend"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1444","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.2,"line_color":"green","x":{"field":"Date"},"y":{"field":"B"}},"id":"1493","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1460","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"formatters":{"@Date":"datetime"},"tooltips":[["Date","@Date{%F}"],["A","@{A}{0,0.0}"],["B","@{B}{0,0.0}"]]},"id":"1508","type":"HoverTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1461","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"green","x":{"field":"Date"},"y":{"field":"B"}},"id":"1492","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1449","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"line_color":"green","x":{"field":"Date"},"y":{"field":"B"}},"id":"1491","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"axis":{"id":"1448"},"coordinates":null,"group":null,"ticker":null},"id":"1451","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1437"}},"id":"1495","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"label":{"value":"B"},"renderers":[{"id":"1494"}]},"id":"1507","type":"LegendItem"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1481","type":"AllLabels"},{"attributes":{"coordinates":null,"data_source":{"id":"1437"},"glyph":{"id":"1472"},"group":null,"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":{"id":"1474"},"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1473"},"view":{"id":"1476"}},"id":"1475","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"root_ids":["1439"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"2.4.3"}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        const fn = function() {
          Bokeh.safely(function() {
            (function(root) {
              function embed_document(root) {
              const docs_json = document.getElementById('1653').textContent;
              const render_items = [{"docid":"1f335636-847c-44ca-ac3d-a39e52279a15","root_ids":["1439"],"roots":{"1439":"4484be71-5c42-4872-ad08-d14d68f5b8be"}}];
              root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
              }
              if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                embed_document(root);
              } else {
                let attempts = 0;
                const timer = setInterval(function(root) {
                  if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    embed_document(root);
                  } else {
                    attempts++;
                    if (attempts > 100) {
                      clearInterval(timer);
                      console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing");
                    }
                  }
                }, 10, root)
              }
            })(window);
          });
        };
        if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
        else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
      })();
    </script>
```

And this is my latest attempt to replace the body with a link to the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
    </script>

<script type="text/html"
src="/assets/bokeh_new/s3_partial.html"
></script>
```

Comment: `file_html` generates an entire, complete HTML page. It is not  a script that can be run in a script tag. There are various other APIs for generating embeddable Bokeh content, you should be using one of those (as intended) instead: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html If you are not willing to do that your only option would be to embed `file_html` output inside an IFrame somehow.

Comment: @bigreddot, thanks. Seems I misunderstood things (again). I'd tried the other methods, but ran into some problems, so came back to the file_html. I'll now have another go with the other APIs.